# Fragment must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

ok i have a slight problem in my Code.

```
public class MenuFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
```

is extending the Sherlock jar which should allow me to use Action bar within my Fragment when i run the Code i am getting

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuFragment must be attached to a SherlockFragmentActivity.
```

So i changed my extends from

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
   public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
```

Which Runs the Code but now my Action bar is no longer visible

My Fragment Class,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return view;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.shuffle:

                return true;
            case R.id.quit:

                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Which is importing

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
```

Main

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SongAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to extend it with `SherlockActivity`

Comment: When i do Sherlock Activity i get  Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.example.dfoley.project2.MenuFragment that is not a Fragment

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm Instead of your

> MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity

just use

```
   MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    //you code for fragment goes here
    }
```

Whatever you use like Fragment you ned to use SherlockFragment, in case of Activity we have SherlockActivity in here. So anything else is not a match.

---

Follow below link you will understand how to go with Sherlock Library: 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments

let me know if this helps.

Comment: What i was hoping to do is have the Main Activity with no Code what so every and place everything into the MenuFragment

Comment: Not Yet.. Still Working on It, SherlockFragmentActivity doesnt Show the ActionBar, and if i use SherlockActivity it crashes.

Comment: have you checked sherlock library is in build path? u need to add more code to have clarity.

Comment: Hi I do have the Sherlock Jar file in build path.. what more code would you like me to add `import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.example.dfoley.project2.Controller.SongAdapter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;`

Comment: wooohoo thats not the code that'll help dear... these are imports only. Well while using SherlockFragmentActivity your app doesnt show actionBar- So have you checked your style.xml ?